# Construct routes(urls) with slugs separated by dash in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am about to make more SEO-friendly URLs on my page and want a pattern looking like this for my products:

[www.example.com/product-category/a-pretty-long-seo-friendly-product-name-12](http://www.example.com/product-category/a-pretty-long-seo-friendly-product-name-12)

So what are we looking at here?

[www.example.com/{slug1}/{slug2}-{id}](http://www.example.com/%7Bslug1%7D/%7Bslug2%7D-%7Bid%7D)

The only thing I will care about from the URL in my controller is the {id}. The rest two slugs are just of SEO purpose. So to my question. How can I get the 12 from a-pretty-long-seo-friendly-product-name-12?

I have tried [www.mydomain.com/{slug}/{slug}-{id}](http://www.mydomain.com/%7Bslug%7D/%7Bslug%7D-%7Bid%7D) and in my controller to try and get $id. Id does not work. I am not able to able to separate it from from a-pretty-long-seo-friendly-product-name. So in my controller no matter how I do I get {slug2} and {id} concatenated.

Coming from rails it is a piece of cake there but can't seem to figure out how to do that here in laravel.

EDIT:
I am sorry I formulated my question very unclear. I am looking for a way to do this in the routes file. Like in rails.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you can't really logically separate `/{slug}-{id}` if you're using dash-separated strings. To handle this, you can simply explode the chunks and select the last one:

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/{primarySlug}/{secondarySlugAndId}', [ExampleController::class, 'example']);

// ExampleController.php
public function example($primarySlug, $secondarySlugAndId){
  $parts = collect(explode('-', $secondarySlugAndId));
  $id = $parts->last();
  $secondarySlug = $parts->slice(0, -1)->implode('-');

  ... // Do anything else you need to do
}
```

Given the URL `example.com/primary-slug/secondary-slug-99`, you would have the following variables:

```php
dd($primarySlug, $secondarySlug, $id);
// "primary-slug"
// "secondary-slug"
// "99"
```

The only case this wouldn't work for is if your `id` had a dash in it, but that's another layer of complexity that I hope you don't have to handle.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Lewis ! I will probably have to do this. I was more looking for a way to do it in the routes file like possible in rails.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Route::get('/test/{slug1}/{slug2}','IndexController@index');

public function index($slug1, $slug2)
{
   $id_slug =  last(explode('-',$slug2));

   $second_slug = str_replace('-'.$id_slug,'',$slug2);

   dd($slug1, $second_slug,$id_slug);
}
```